# ggplot2 geom_bar plot Labels fall outside plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

#### Question

I'm trying to locate labels of a bar plot using ggplot2 over the bars.
The problem I get is that the labels fall "outside" the plot.

#### Load packages

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
```

#### Barplot

```
df_1 <- data.frame(PROV = c("BUENOS AIRES", "BUENOS AIRES", "BUENOS AIRES"),
                   variable = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"), 
                   value = c(15, 20, 5))

col_bar <- c("#00BA38", "#00BFC4", "#D7BA00")

z = ggplot(df_1, aes(x = factor(variable), y = value)) +
   geom_bar(data=df_1, stat = "identity", fill = col_bar) +
   geom_text(aes(label=value), colour= col_bar, size = 7, vjust = -1)

z = z + theme(panel.background = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.border = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
z = z + theme(plot.background = element_blank())
z = z + theme(plot.background = element_blank())
z = z + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
z = z + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

print(z)
```

Comment: Increase the limits of the y axis using `ylim`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a good solution for the previous example. 
I'll answer the question to leave the reference.

```
z = ggplot(df_1, aes(x = factor(variable), y = value)) +
   geom_bar(data=df_1, stat = "identity", fill = col_bar) +
   geom_text(aes(label=value), colour= col_bar, size = 7, vjust = -1)

z = z + theme(panel.background = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.border = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
z = z + theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
z = z + theme(plot.background = element_blank())
z = z + theme(plot.background = element_blank())
z = z + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
z = z + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
z = z + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,23)) 
print(z)
```